# Can anyone read this note (found hidden in a 1st edition copy of Alexander von Humboldt's Kosmos)

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

This note was hidden in a set of books I recently bought (Kosmos by Alexander von Humboldt, 1st edition 1845). I recognise dates (April 1839, 1840) and sums, so this might be some note about costs or accounting. But I can't make out most of the text. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: If the answer below solved your query satisfactorily, please mark it as "accepted" (the green checkmark right beside the beginning of the answer). This way, everybody knows that it was solved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had some fun with it.

No guarantees, and I didn't get everything. Thanks to @ccprog and @marquinho for their additions.

```
Nota von Zimmermeist[er] ???d Fuhr
für Mauermeist[er] Bell(?) in Kehmel über
gefertigte Arbeit an dem Herrn Gasthalter
Lang dahier seynen Saalbau.
1837 Juni 5t. habe ich die hintere Grund Mauer=
  werk gestreckt mit zwey Hebgescher  
  und fünf Mann[,] betr[agend]      6 Th 
"    "    6t. habe ich dito das Gübelmauer=
  werk gestreckt mit einem Gescher  3 Th 30
                                    ------
              S.[umma] s.[ummarum]  9 Th 30
    
L.[angen] Schwalbach den 27ten April 1839   
bezahlt d. 5ten Feb 1840 mit 3 Th 30
weil es strittig wahr
```

The village "Kehmel" is now written *Kemel*. A "Gasthalter" is an innkeeper. The name of the "Maurermeister" could be Bell, Boll or Bull, not sure.

There are some grammatical incongruencies, I just left them how I read them, as well as the spelling.

I also don't really know what "Mauerwerk mit einem Hebgescher strecken" means. I understand that a *Hebgescher* is what would be written *Hebgeschirr* today, which means 'lifting gear', but I have no knowledge about this craft.

One could speculate about what the purpose of this "nota" (note) was, could be a receipt if Bell ordered these works. "Th" probably means Thaler, see the comment about the ["Kronenthaler"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronenthaler).

They did pay late in those days already...

Edit: more speculation: maybe [this Andreas Fuhr](https://www.hohenemsgenealogie.at/gen/getperson.php?personID=I39630&tree=Hohenems) or his son?

Comment: I read Gasthalter **Haug** and **weiß gestreicht** as in "painted white". "seynen" is written with y. Comparing the way the letter H is written in other places, I suspect **H. Schwalbach**. – As for the purpose, it is a receipt, I would think.

Comment: @ccprog A letter "u" in Haug would need a Kringel above the letter. I'm not sure about the H. Definitely not "weiß gestreicht", which doesn't fit the letters at all imo and also wouldn't make sense for a "Zimmermann".

Comment: Identifying the Gasthof [won't be easy](https://www.heidenrod.de/geschichte-ortsteile/): "Die Straßenanlagen Kemels brachten es mit sich, dass es weiterhin eine bekannten Raststätte blieb... 1788 waren am Ort neun Gasthöfe vorhanden..."

Comment: @HalvarF Exactly: There is little doubt that both those lines read "werk gestreckt", and in both cases the previous line ends with "Mauer=", giving "Mauerwerk". The "H"s in the sums actually read "th", which ought to stand for "Thaler".

Comment: The words up to "betr.", right before the first payable sum, I interpret as follows: "und fünf Mann[,] betr[ägt] 6 th."

Comment: Hessen-Nassau [at the time](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herzogtum_Nassau#W%C3%A4hrung_und_M%C3%BCnzen) was traditionally using Gulden and Kreuzer for currency. The [Kronentaler](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronentaler) was minted between 1816 and 1837, when the _Münchner Münzvertrag_ introduced a common Gulden for southern Germany.

Comment: Now I have it: L. Schwalbach is the neighbouring town to Heidenrod, today [Bad Schwalbach](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Schwalbach), but at the time called Langenschwalbach.

Comment: @ccprog Great catch! Now, comparing the L in "L. Schwalbach" with the first letter in the innkeeper's name, it is clear to me that it is an L, too.

Comment: Thanks for all your great additions, I edited accordingly.

Comment: A (new) small typo: it's "3 Th 30", not "6 Th 30"

Comment: @marquinho yes, thanks. I made the answer a community wiki because of all of your additions. Feel free to edit should new issues (or ideas) appear.